# Displaying usage of a program

Tags: linux

I am working on a .c program in linux and my assignment contain a task that require me to display the usage of the program when invoked as follows:

```
$./filename -help
```

the whole program itself requires me to read a value from the command line and get two .wav files to input:

```
$./filename x file1.wav file2.wav
```

So how do i put multiple purposes to the .c program "filename" itself? I am new to linux and am quite lost at this.

Comment: how abt some web search? rather looking for ready to eat stuff !!!!!

Comment: BTW, ordinarily, it is `--help` with two dashes (and rather `-x` than just `x`); you need to process the arguments to `main`

Answer (score 2):

The program needs to examine the `argv` array which gets passed to `main()` and behave in accordance with the specified options.

This is commonly done using [library routines](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments).